# Zclip Open only clicked class/copy from next element

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, copy, zclip

I've realized how bad i'm at JS/jQuery not having used it for decades.

I'm using [jQuery Zclip](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/) to copy text from a list. But I found out that it first only works on one element per page. I found a solution using a different ID for every list item, but this will create a lot of unnecessary work in the future since there will be a ton of buttons.

What I need is a function that checks the span element AFTER the button element and take the content from that, rather from a specific ID. How can I achieve this through jquery?

Here's my HTML/JS

```
<li><span class="server-name">SERVER NAME</span>
    <br><button class="copy">COPY</button>IP:<span class="server-ip">127.0.0.1</span>
</li>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button.copy').zclip({
        path: 'scripts/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: $('span.description').text()
  });
```

I hope you understand my question.

Comment: @Satpal is correct - it's even in the [usage](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/#usage) page

Comment: @Regent, You can go through source code http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/jquery.zclip.js                    `o.bind('zClip_copy',settings.copy);`

Comment: @Regent True, but `beforeCopy` and `afterCopy` on the page exhibit this behaviour, so I assumed `copy` would too

Comment: @Satpal yeah, even though it's abnormal to see plugin source code to understand how it works, I've done exactly this, and yes - I've found the same line, +1.

Comment: I checked the usage page and didn't find the solution there, that's why I came here. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use function with copy like

```
$('button.copy').zclip({
    path: 'scripts/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy: function() {
        return $(this).next('.server-ip').text(); //this here refers to element which invoked zclip
    }
});
```

You can go through [source code](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/jquery.zclip.js)

```
o.bind('zClip_copy',settings.copy);
```

Comment: @FredrikWesterlund yes, especially concerning that Satpal was the first to suggest this idea :)

Comment: @Regent, I should not have deleted the comment.

Comment: Since i'm not really comfortable with js, looking through the source could would not help me much i'm afraid.

Who suggested it first? I looked at the timepstamp and "approved" after that.

Comment: @FredrikWesterlund since `zclip` plugin developers were not comfortable with writing this important moment in docs, we are stuck with looking source code... Nevertheless, I suppost the link to source code is here as proof, not as "you should look in it".

Comment: @FredrikWesterlund Satpal suggested it in comments 16 minutes ago, but then deleted comment to make it an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like `copy` parameter can be a function. If it is invoked (and looks like it is) in context of the current button, then the next code should work as you want:

```
$('button.copy').zclip({
    path: 'scripts/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy: function() {
        return $(this).next('.server-ip').text();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Give your `li` a class (something like `info`:

```
<li class="info">
    <span class="server-name">SERVER NAME</span>
    <button class="copy">COPY</button>
    IP:<span class="server-ip">127.0.0.1</span>
</li>
```

And in your JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // loop through all `.info` elements
    $('.info').each(function () {
        // get the button
        var $button = $(this).find('.copy');

        // get the ip element
        var $ip = $(this).find('.server-ip');

        // make button zclip
        $button.zclip({
            path: 'scripts/ZeroClipboard.swf',

            // the text of ip
            copy: $ip.text()
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This solution seems to work great, thanks!
Thanks for the thorough description of the script, it helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know `zclip`, but you need to select text from next element behind button, so the fourth line should be:

```
copy: $(this).next('.server-ip').text()
```

Comment: When using this solution copies blank. :/
But it's in the right direction I think.